# Is communication effective without the logical connectives such as or, and, implies, not, if and only if?

Tags: logic

Is communication effective without the logical connectives such as or, and, implies, not, if and only
if ?

I know the answer is no but how can it explain it in detail.

I know I cannot say "A is not B" without using logical connectives.

Comment: The answer is not no.  I can still issue a command like "pick up my bags" without using logical connectives.

Comment: One thing that that is tricky about this is that the words and or ect do not need to be used in order to use the ideas. For instance I ca say the following are true, then simply list the following.

Answer (score 4):

A short poem by Blake goes:

> Never pain to tell the love,
>
> Love that never told can be;
>
> For the gentle wind does move
>
> Silently, invisibly.
>
> I told my love, I told my love,
>
> I told her all my heart;
>
> Trembling, cold, in ghastly fears,
>
> Ah! she doth depart.
>
> Soon as she was gone from me,
>
> A traveller came by,
>
> Silently, invisibly;
>
> Oh was no deny.

There are no 'logical' connectives here. Having said this, 'logical' connectives  are not traditionally part of the vocabulary of linguists. It is part of the vocabulary of computer science - and specifically that of the design of computer languages.

Babies learn speech on small fragments of conversation which one suspects do not have the 'logical' connectives that you mention. Surely communication is happening here.

In a much wider context, semiotics, the science of signs and signifiers, communication happens without 'logical' connectives. For example, the display of a clock. Perhaps one could imagine signage in an airport offering options so are implicitly offering the logical connective 'or' - but then could not one imagine that a brick on the floor offering implicitly a range of options - as in pick it up and put it in on a nearby table OR pick it up and chuck it at a window?

Telling someone to F*** O** brutally conveys a message, as does hitting someone. People communicate by facial expression, by their posture and motion.

In short - effective communication does happen without 'logical connectives.

Comment: Interesting and good answer in total, but a small correction: logical connectives are definitely traditionally part of the vocabulary of linguists.

Comment: Indeed, logical connectives would tend to fall in the categories of "conjunctions" ('AND', 'IF', and 'OR'), verbs ('IMPLIES'), and verb phrases ('IS EQUIVALENT TO') syntactically. Nevertheless, +1 for channelling Wittgenstein on the matter of logical form.

Comment: @Eric'3ToedSloth': It's clear that I shouldn't assert when I've made an educated guess as to the provenance of the term 'logical connectives'. Logic is traditionally the prerogative of philosophy. 'And','or','not' were recognised in logic, obviously by Booles time, but also well before then - by theophrastus, Aristotles successor and also the stoic philosophers. My guess is the term migrated from philosophy into linguistics. But I'm probably being too simplistic here.

Answer (score 0):

One way to say "A is not B" without using logical connectives is to say "'A is B' is false." We do not need the logical connectives (or logic period) to effectively communicate claims about the truth/falsity of statements. The logical connectives just provide more *efficient* ways of communicating the same content.

Comment: Allowing the construction "'X' is false" this is adds a truth-functional relation to the language, which is at least as powerful as adding a negation operator.

Answer (score 0):

There are [four types of sentences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentence_function): declarative, interrogative, imperative and exclamatory.

The meanings of declarative sentences can generally be conveyed entirely with logical forms, if we iron-out metaphors, such as this, for example. All the other types need a bit more than simple statements in the logical form. Interrogatives [expose bare lambda expressions](http://www.sfb632.uni-potsdam.de/~simik/pdf/simik-egg-intro-questions.pdf). In imperatives, the argument of the exposed lambda expressions [is the addressee](http://semanticsarchive.net/Archive/mJlZGQ4N/PortnerSALT04.pdf). Exclamatory sentences may have any of the above forms, but convey something else entirely. Of course, all these apply to just verbal communication. Even non-verbal communication can be effective, i.e. accomplish its intended purpose.